# Lubuntu 19.04 Screensaver locks during video playback

Tags: lubuntu, video, lock-screen, screensaver, lxqt

Pretty much as the subject says, the screensaver keeps activating and locking me out while I'm watching a long video, even while in full-screen.  I've been able to find posts discussing this issue in Ubuntu or in earlier (non-LXQt) versions of Lubuntu, but I haven't seen it for 18.10+ yet (gnome-tweaks isn't going to help much here).

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

(Edit: I had the wrong version listed initially; I'm still seeing the error in 19.04.)

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10 is EOL (end-of-life; https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-etc-eol/) as are all 18.10 releases as it was not a LTS release, so you should have release-upgraded to 19.04 already.  Stick to LTS releases if you don't like release-upgrading every 6-9 months (18.10 = 2018.October + 9 months of life)

Comment: This problem persists to Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

Some programs are not really handling correctly the prevention of the screensaver, so I found really handy to use [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) whenever I was in trouble.

Can be easily installed as:

```
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

There is also an indicator included in the program(caffeine-indicator) so you can make it run on startup so that you have the indicator be displayed in the tray to enable it whenever you want

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that, could you expand on your answer? thank you.